# How should I create a matrix of costs based on a set of variable?

Tags: linear-programming, decision-theory, utility

I'm trying to make a matrix that depicts costs for a set of tasks. These tasks are the rows of the matrix. The cost matrix is to be based on a multi-attribute weightage of the tasks based on their parameters such as temporal urgency, importance, etc. Now I dont know what kind of a mathematical model to use to get such a cost matrix, as it is to be an input for a linear program, which is what I am studying right now. Can someone point me in the kind of direction I should be looking for such a thing?

Comment: Given your specific requirements, the best mathematical model to use is given by the matrix $C=(c_{ij})$ where $$c_{ij} = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
ij&\mbox{ if either $i$ or $j$ is prime} \\
42 & \mbox{ otherwise} 
\end{array}
\right.$$ This is as described in the _SIAM Journal on Correct Cost Matrices_, June 2018: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=the+answer+to+the+ultimate+question+of+life,+the+universe,+and+everything

Comment: I understand its vague but I just need to understand what kind of stuff I need to read about to be able to do what I have mentioned in the question